# Is Sergei Krikalev living slightly in the future, or is his body just younger than it otherwise would have been?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, time-dilation, satellites

Due to cosmonaut [Sergei Krikalev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Krikalev)'s time on board space station Mir in Earth orbit, the combined effects of velocity and gravity have caused him to experience an accumulated 20 milliseconds of time dilation compared to an observer on Earth's surface.  I'm curious what this means for him in practice, though (however slight)--is his entire experience of life and the world twenty milliseconds ahead of where it is for the rest of us, or (just for one, perhaps trivial, example) will his wrinkles on his skin as he ages just appear 20 milliseconds later than they otherwise would have?

Comment: Here's a relevant answer to a related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/150142. When two identical clocks take non-identical journeys between two meetings, they typically show different amounts of elapsed time between those meetings. We can use relativity in curved spacetime to predict which clock shows less elapsed time. This is called the **twin paradox**, and it's a spacetime analog of the familiar fact that different paths in space that cross each other twice typically have different lengths between those two crossings.

Comment: On my way home from work today I took a five mile detour.  My wife, who works at the same place, drove straight home.  Does this just mean I drove five miles further than she did, or does it mean that we are now living five miles apart?

Answer (score 6):

Let me try to make an analogy:

Suppose you and I both start at town A and we drive to town B. We take different routes and it turns out that your route is 20 metres shorter than mine, so although we start at the same place and end at the same place you have travelled 20 metres less than me and your car is 20 metres less worn out than mine.

This is travelling in space, but we are all also travelling in time. If I start at 2 p.m. and get to 3 p.m. I have travelled in time by 3600 seconds. Pre-Einstein, if we both started at 2 p.m. and got to 3 p.m. we have both travelled the same distance in time. There is no sense in which we could travel by different routes in time.

However in relativity we are all travelling in *spacetime*, and travel in space and travel in time are inextricably related. Suppose I shake hands with Sergei Krikalev before he departed for the ISS, then shake hands with him again on his return. My time distance, i.e. the distance I travelled in time in between the two handshakes, would be 20 ms greater than Krikalev's. This is what we mean by *time dilation*. Sergei Krikalev would indeed be 20 ms less worn out (to return to the car analogy) than I am.

There is no sense in which he is living in the *future*. We both started at the same time and returned to the same time, it's just that he took a shorter path through spacetime between those two points than I did and consequently aged 20 ms less.